# VBA Excel-Select UsedRange of data in Column instead of entire column

Tags: excel, vba

See code below. I'm trying to select the column data-not the entire column. So, possibly just looking to change something about the code to "UsedRange"?

```
'Select entire column-need to select only USED RANGE

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgUni As Range
Dim xFirstAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
On Error Resume Next
xStr = "FEE RATE"
Set xRg = Range("A1:AA1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
    xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
    Do
        Set xRg = Range("A1:AA1").FindNext(xRg)
        If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
            Set xRgUni = xRg
        Else
            Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
        End If
    Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
End If
xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: will more than 1 column be involved?

Comment: Try `Application.Intersect(UsedRange, xRgUni.EntireColumn).Select` but it's not really clear what you need to do here.  For example in the case of multiple columns are you expecting them all to be the same size (# of rows)?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to select 2 different columns using this. The goal is to copy a BLANK CELL, then SELECT the data in columns titled  "PROC#/REV CODE" and "FEE RATE", then PASTE SPECIAL and ADD. Tim Williams, the code you recommend does not work for me. It does not select the column.

Comment: @LittleZenGirl; please see the edited answer in your previous question.